# How to get the division part of a number

Tags: php, language-agnostic

Say I have 1.234  I want to get the .234 
I tried `echo 1.234%1 //I get 0`
I am rusty, what is the correct way?

(The tags says PHP as this might be an issue only with PHP, but I really am looking for the general solution).

Comment: `$x = $x - floor($x)`

from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-fractional-part-of-a-float-in-php

Comment: The answer to this question is contained within https://stackoverflow.com/q/6619377/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa see the answer I accepted vs the answers in the thread u linked to.

Comment: Stack Overflow is flooded with redundant content.  I am trying to relate what has not yet been related by the system.  `fmod()` is demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33562331/2943403

Comment: I see it in another way.
Software changes, I expect to see same questions over and over, with new answers all the time. It is admirable what u try to do. But I would use this effort to create something rather than cleaning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php's `%` [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) converts its arguments to integers. To get a floating-point modulus, use [`fmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php):

```
echo fmod(1.234, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the whole number from the number itself. in php its:

```
$num = 1.234;
echo $num - floor($num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the integer portion of $x (`(int)$x`) from $x:

```
$x = 1.234;
$d = $x - (int)$x;
// $d now equals 0.234
echo $d;
```

[Example](http://codepad.org/6yMNgpJf)

Answer (score 0):

Just substract integer part `1.234 - (int)1.234`

Comment: 2.5 % 0.6 = 0.1   2.5 - 2 = 0.5;;;;; 2.5 %0.5 = 0   2.5-2 = 0.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

echo 1.234 - intval(1.234);