# Can the PHP function microtime return an integer even if return as float is set to true?

Tags: php

A user of my website reported an error the other day so I had a look through the logs and tracked it down. The error was:

```
Undefined offset: 1
```

The code in question that caused this error was:

```
$parts = explode('.', microtime(true));
$nonce = base_convert($parts[1], 10, 36);
```

So $parts[1] was undefined basically. Could this be because when microtime was called it just so happened that it was an exact second so it returned an int without any decimal places?

Comment: What php version? depending on php version i once had this error and fixed it by removing something let me know what version

Comment: It returns `123123123.` float with probability `1/1000000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test can confirm your assumption:

```
<?php

while (true) {
    $microtime = microtime(true);

    $tmp = explode('.', $microtime, 2);

    if (sizeof($tmp) === 1) {
        var_dump($microtime);
        break;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
float(1508171125)
```

On my system. So yes, `microtime` can return an "integer".

It makes sense if you think about it, a round number doesn't need the comma separator.

For creating nonce values I suggest using `random_bytes()` (if you are using PHP7) or `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` which are a lot safer than `microtime`.

Comment: It is float still, but with zero microseconds part.

Comment: @vp_arth Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't operate with floats as with strings.

`microfloat(true)` returns `\d+` float with probability `1/1000000`.

Your code should be like followed:

```
$time = microtime(true);
$frac = ($time - floor($time))*1e6;
$nonce = base_convert($frac, 10, 36);
```

Or much better:

```
$nonce = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a quick test function for you:

```
<?php
while(true) {
    $a= microtime(true);
    if ($a == intval($a)) {
       echo "no fraction part";
       break;
    }
}
```

So - the answer is "yes".

Anyway: you should have a look into this question/answer:
[What's the best way to get the fractional part of a float in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801/whats-the-best-way-to-get-the-fractional-part-of-a-float-in-php)

because using a string method to get the fraction part of a float is kind of "special" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
**YES**

https://3v4l.org/YF2v8

The float will act as a number would. So if there are zeroes at the end of it, after a comma, they won't be displayed as it's a number, not a string. And 1.00000 = 1.

You may go around the problem by multiplying the `microtime()` result by 1000000 and then calculating a little more.

If all else fails, you'll get a number like:
1508171140000000

In your code, you'd have to patch it with, for example:

```
base_convert($parts[1] ?? 0, 10, 36);
```

[image]